# Subscribing to observable generates second http get (HttpClient)

Tags: angular

Why when adding the subscription below do I see a second call to get the JSON in the chrome developer network tab?

The second call is a few milliseconds later and shows a full request & response

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  repositories: Observable<Array<any>>;

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {

    const path = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=angular&sort=stars&order=desc';

    this.repositories = http.get<any>(path).pipe(map(obj => obj.items));

    // adding this subscription creates 
    // a second call for the JSON?
    this.repositories.subscribe(next => {
      localStorage['repoCache'] = JSON.stringify(next);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the first request of `OPTIONS` type ?

Comment: why dont you try just this : this.repositories = http.get<any>(path); and then this.repositories.subscribe)

Comment: "Is the first request of OPTIONS type ? "
They are both HTTP gets
I don't see a type indicator, sorry.

Comment: You can refer to share(). Read https://blog.flyt.tech/reducing-http-requests-within-an-angular-2-app-a904ac47fc7

Comment: can you show the used template, did you use the asyncPipe ( | async ) in your template ? Because the asyncPipe already does a subscribe on the observable passed in parameter

Comment: Yes, I use async
Trying to figure out how I could make just one http call


    <div *ngFor="let repo of repositories | async">
      <ul class="li">{{repo.name}}</ul>
    </div>

Comment: Seems to be a simple fix  
Thank you all  

    // add an additional import  
    import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';  

    // include share() in the pipe  
    this.repositories = http.get<any>(path).pipe(map(obj => obj.items), share());

Answer (score 0):

You probably have something like this on your template:

```
<div *ngIf="repositories">
  <li *ngFor="let repository of (repositories | async)">{{repository.name}}</li>
</div>
```

"async" generates a subscription and you have another one on the component. Each subscription will fire the observable, thus generating two HTTP calls.

Lastly, I would recommend not to do http calls on the constructor, instead implement the "OnInit" method, which is a better place in the lifecycle of a component for that type of work.